# IUpdateSearchers BrowseOnly=1 returning (wrongly) 0

Tags: c++, windows, windows-update

I am trying to collect not already installed, non optional Windows Updates for a machine via IUpdateSearcher, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064647/how-to-discover-if-windows-update-is-optional-recommended-or-important/26121487#26121487).

[IUpdateSearchers documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states the updates could be filtered via the BrowseOnly criterion. Yet it does not seem to work for me, this code:

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

ISearchResult *pResult;
IUpdateSession *pSession;
IUpdateSearcher *pSearcher;

CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UpdateSession, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUpdateSession, (LPVOID*)&pSession);
pSession->CreateUpdateSearcher(&pSearcher);

LONG updateSizeT, updateSizeB1, updateSizeB0;
IUpdateCollection *pCollection;

BSTR criteria = SysAllocString(L"IsInstalled=0");
pSearcher->Search(criteria, &pResult);
pResult->get_Updates(&pCollection);
pCollection->get_Count(&updateSizeT);

SysFreeString(criteria);
criteria = SysAllocString(L"IsInstalled=0 and BrowseOnly=0");
pSearcher->Search(criteria, &pResult);
pResult->get_Updates(&pCollection);
pCollection->get_Count(&updateSizeB0);

SysFreeString(criteria);
criteria = SysAllocString(L"IsInstalled=0 and BrowseOnly=1");
pSearcher->Search(criteria, &pResult);
pResult->get_Updates(&pCollection);
pCollection->get_Count(&updateSizeB1);

SysFreeString(criteria);
wcout << L"Total: " << updateSizeT << endl
    << L"BrowseOnly=0: " << updateSizeB0 << endl
    << L"BrowseOnly=1: " << updateSizeB1 << endl;
```

Produces the following output:

```
Total: 86
BrowseOnly=0: 49
BrowseOnly=1: 0
```

Other than the code being ugly, what am I doing wrong?
Even more checking the Windows Update Control Panel shows there should be 0 non-optional (BrowseOnly=0) updates, yet the codes returns 49.